# Finding a (linear) interpolant between values on the surface of an d-dimensional unit hyper-sphere

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy, interpolation, geospatial

I'm looking to find a way to define a (possibly linear) interpolant using n values that exist on the surface of a d-dimensional unit hyper-sphere. The samples we are interpolating between on the surface can be anywhere (non-uniform), and take the value of either -1 or 1.

I have a potential solution, but it feels a little heavy-handed, and so I wondered if there might be a better way.

For simplicity, imagine the d=2 scenario (a circle) with n arbitary points on the edge of the circle defined as either -1 or 1. We can define a unique point on the boundary of the circle using a single value, we simply need to pick an arbitary vector u that goes from the centre of the circle to the boundary and measure the angle each other point has from this reference point. From this perspective, the edge of the circle can be seen as the closed interval [0, 2pi] where the points 0 and 2pi are the same point. We can then create a simple linear interpolant R between these points such that picking any point on the boundary gives a value in the interval [-1, 1].

[visualisation of how the 2-d scenario becomes a 1-d interpolant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkVWO.png)

I want to find a practical way to do this for a d-dimensional problem.

You can define a unique point on the surface of a d-dimensional hyper-sphere using d-1 variables. Again, we just find an arbitary reference vector u whose origin is the centre of the hyper-sphere, pick d-1 planes in the space that are all orthogonal to each other and measure the angle each interpolant point between them all via a vector spanning the space between the origin and the interpolant point. We therefore have that defining a unique point on a d-dimensional hypershpere is simply [0, 2pi]x[0, 2pi]x...[0, 2pi] d-1 times.

Given that, we then have (l1, l2, ..., lm)=1 are positive points on the surface, and (p1, p2, ..., pk)=-1 are negative points on the surface, we can simply use:

```
scipy.interpolate.interpn([l1,..., lm, p1,..., pk], [1, ..., 1, -1, ..., -1], v, method='linear')[source]
```

This easily creates the type of (d-1)-dimensional interpolant I want, where v is the sample point (as the angles from the reference vector u). However, the major issue here is that this interpolant does not take into account the infinite nature of the hyper-sphere. In other words, when I cross the boundary, I reappear again at the other boundary. Therefore I require the interpolant to agree at all boundaries. I can enforce this by making copies of the space to simulate the infinite nature of the sphere. For example, in the 2-d case (circle) I consider the interval [-2pi, 4pi] where [-2pi, 0] and [2pi, 4pi] are just copies of the values in [0, 2pi]. But this isn't a scalable solution, as each dimension added requires 2^(d-1) copies.

I am wondering if there is an interpolant function that takes this into account anyway (e.g. in geospatial problems, where the earth is looping, closed 3-dimensional sphere). Or perhaps I have framed this issue in a needlessly complex way.

Comment: Are `lm` and `pk` tuples or lists of values from 0 to 2pi and each describe a single point in space?

Comment: By definition each dimension is perpendicular to all other dimensions so each angle in any hyperplane is independent of any other: measure the angular difference in each hyperplane, then lerp those independently to get the full interpolation.

Comment: l and p are exactly that. On a hypersphere of d dimensions, each value of l and p is a list of d-1 values where each value is somewhere in [0, 2pi] describing the angle from the reference vector u. Each l and p therefore describes a single point on the surface of the hypersphere.